# Reset python from 3 to 2 after anaconda modified PATH

Tags: python, environment-variables

I've installed anaconda and last thing it asked was if it could change the path. It actually installed python 3

```
samuel@samuel-pc:~$ python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I want the default python to be 2.7.x or just 2.7 since all my django project ceased to work after this and I'd rather revert for now than try and find why for example static and media files no longer serve.

Comment: Anaconda modifies your PATH to put its own directory first, I believe. If you don't want to uninstall anaconda, you can try just revoking the change to your PATH (check `~/.profile` to see if the reassignment is there (looks something like `PATH=/path/to/anaconda/bin:$PATH`) and comment it out. If not, check `~/.bashrc`)

Comment: Great :) You can post an answer to your own question explaining what you did, if you would like (which file was it?)

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal  and type:

```
sudo -H gedit ~/.profile
```

This will open an editor. Check if there is a path for Python 3.

If in the above step you couldn't find the Python 3 environment variable, run:

```
sudo -H gedit ~/.bashrc
```

look for a Python 3 environment variable, and comment it out.